# Remote Desktop by computer name doesn't work, but does by IP address

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

I have a remote office that connects to our main office through a watchguard VPN.

I cannot Remote Desktop to a machine in the remote office by computer name, but Remote Desktop does work if I specify the remote machine's IP address instead.

Can anyone advise what might be causing this?

Comment: It means your DNS query is not working... Ask whoever is in charge of the VPN to ensure VPN clients have access to the DNS server

Comment: If the remote machine has a fixed address, then a work-round is to add the name-to-IP map to your `hosts` file.